# get repo source URL from apt install --dry-run

Tags: debian, apt

Running `apt install --dry-run` gives me the following output:

```
Inst gpg [2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2] (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates, Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-security [amd64]) [gpg-wks-server:amd64 gnupg:amd64 ]
Inst libswresample3 [7:4.3.1-1ubuntu0~18.04.sav0] (7:4.3.1-1ubuntu0~18.04.sav1 FFmpeg 4 - media tool (Xenial & newer):18.04/bionic [amd64]) []
```

How can I get the origin of each package in terms of a URL or local path as written in the `/etc/apt/source.list`? There is a loose resemblance on identifiers displayed with `apt policy` which happens to also print the URL.
The exact connection is not clear...

What I need ultimately is a list of repositories required to install a specific high-level package that may have dependencies into several repositories.